# How to change the parent reusable component's style from it's child component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I'm using a reusable component in my current component. But i want to change the style of my reusable component. How can i override the parent reusable component style in my child component.

Parent reusable component:(settings-panel.component.html)

```
<button>
    <app-svg-icon [iconSrc]="iconSrc"></app-svg-icon>
</button>
<div [ngClass]="position" class="settings-panel" [hidden]="!panelIsVisible">
    <span class="arrow"></span>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

This is my current component(outage.component.html)

```
 <app-settings-panel class="outage-main" iconPath="alert.svg" position="right bottom">
     <div class="outage-panel">
        <div class="outage-heading">
            <span>Notifications</span>
            <span>New</span>
        </div>      
        <span *ngFor="let outage of outageArray">
            <button type="button" class="outage-group-item">
                <span>{{outage}}</span>
            </button>
        </span>
     </div>
 </app-settings-panel>
```

This is my current component (outage.component.scss)

```
.outage-main{
    div:nth-child(1) {
            border: 5px solid red !important; 
    }
}
```

Here i'm trying to change the parent component's div style. But it is not changing the parent div style. It is changing the style of div in my current component.

How can i change the style in my settings-panel.component.html?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors but be aware that in will be ireversible

Comment: @Vega Thank you so much. Yeah i got it

Answer (score 0):

According to @vega comment, i read about :host and this solves my problem

```
 :host ::ng-deep app-settings-panel {

      div.settings-panel {
          border: 5px solid red !important;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Ideally a property should inherit from parent to child and then maybe overridden. The child may send messages which may be used at parent level... What you are trying to do is an architecture danger